# Problem with encoding in R when opening packages

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've sucesfully downloaded and installed "ggplot2". I can't open it with the library command.

Here's what happens:

`library(ggplot2)
Erro: package or namespace load failed for ‘ggplot2’ in get(Info[i, 1], envir = env):
 não foi possível abrir o arquivo 'C:/Users/TÃ©o/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/rlang/R/rlang.rdb': No such file or directory`

There seems to be a problem with the encoding. The part "C:/Users/TÃ©o/Documents/" should be "C:/Users/**Téo**/Documents/"

How can I change this? Thanks

Comment: I would try to experiment with `Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", 'YourLang');
Sys.setenv(LANG = "YourLang")` try to experiment with this in runtime and if have success set it in Your `.Rprofile`:
`if(!file.exists("~/.Rprofile")) # only create if not already there
  file.create("~/.Rprofile")    # (don't overwrite it)
file.edit("~/.Rprofile")`

Comment: The system is already set in the correct language: `Sys.getlocale()
[1] "LC_COLLATE=Portuguese_Brazil.1252;LC_CTYPE=Portuguese_Brazil.1252;LC_MONETARY=Portuguese_Brazil.1252;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=Portuguese_Brazil.1252"`

Comment: Everything seems normal when I type .libPaths(): `.libPaths()
[1] "C:/Users/Téo/Documents/R/win-library/4.0"
[2] "C:/Program Files/R/R-4.0.0/library"`